# NA() function is returning #### rather than the string #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a lab in school we are working with a datasheet, of which has #N/A strings for invalid data which is pulled from previous sheet as being a 0 length string (since the actual cells have formulas in them and aren't 'blank')

I am using NA() in a IF function as follows.

`=IF(LEN(data!$D3)=0, NA(), data!$D3)`

This gives the cell the #### value rather than the text value #N/A that I thought it should.

Where as applying the string directly "#N/A" doesn't work for the chart to exclude the data points and it plots it as a zero value.

Where as the NA() function does work and the chart does exclude the data however the entry into the sheet is wrong.

Basically.  How do I use or have equivalent function of NA function (when I mouse over the cell it shows #N/A) and actually has the visible value #N/A instead of ####, that will allow a chart to ignore that data point.

Below is a link to the excel sheet, I am working on the Transform sheet, of which cell B3 has the modified above formula
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sxhwZyfb2gAbhl58hRB647QqZSDSDaRr

Comment: Increase your column width

Comment: That was the issue thanks, totally missed that.